# Best way to Read and process large file with 50 million rows (8GB). After POJO creation Store in Mongo DB

Tags: java, mongodb, collections, filereader

```
ListIterator it= FileUtils.lineIterator(bigFile);
List<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();
//Iterate and add lines to list
while(it.hasNext){
    rows.add(it.next())// Exception1 
}
//ExecutorService to Iterate a chunk of 20K rows 
// In Executor create do validations and create pojo List
// exeutor service to iterate Pojo list and save 20k chunk pojo in mongo db
```

Issues/ Exception:.
  1.   Unable to create list named rows,  Getting outOfMemory heap exception.
  2.    If i do not create list and process each row and store in mongo. It will take a lot of time and may also lead to other exceptions.
What is the best approach to read and process such large file?

Comment: You have to process the big file in batches. Read one batch (i.e. 20k lines), transform each line to a POJO, store each POJO in a temp list of max 20k elements, then store the list in MongoDB (Mongo has a saveAll or similar approach). Do it sequentially. Then, only if you are not happy with performance, we might start talking about doing things in parallel.

Comment: How about reading a line, add to blocking queue. There would be multiple consumer threads. These consumers will fetch data in chunks of 5K and create pojo and store in mongo Db. Please let me know if there is a better approach to this

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner the way you suggested is best. I tried creating blocking queue with a producer and multiple consumers. Even that takes same amount of time i.e 7mins to store to mongo. But sending to kafka takes about 35 minutes. Is there anything that can be done

Comment: Nothing I can tell from this question and without actually working in the real project, sorry.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner No problem..thanks

Answer (score 0):

2 GB of bytes will double as `String` normally will contain a `char[]` and `char` is a two bytes UTF-16 value.

Best would be to have some compression, maybe on 20 KB chunks of the file as mentioned. The application can also be given more memory `-DXmax=2g`.

Your code assumes the huge file is plain text (or HTML or an SQL dump or a log file).

I have done a line based compression (which is not that good, even negative for empty lines).

```
Path path = Paths.get(bigFile); // String bigFile
Path path = bigFile.toPath(); // File bigFile
Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset(); // Or whatever the charset is.
List<byte[]> compressedLines = Files.lines(path, charset)
    .map(line -> compress(line)) // Or compress(line + "\n")
    .collect(Collectors.toList());


byte[] compress(String s) {
    byte[] content = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (GZipOutputStream out = new GZipOutputStream(baos)) {
        out.write(content);
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}

String decompress(byte[] compressed) {
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (GZipInputStream in = new GZipInputStream(bais)) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[128];
        for (;;) {
            int nread = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
            if (nread <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            baos.write(buf, 0, nread);
        }
    }
    return new String(baos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

This might not be the best solution as-is.